# Embedded Keycloak integration with DB2

Tags: spring-boot, db2, keycloak

I know that official support for DB2 does not exist for Keycloak. However, I am trying to integrate my Keycloak Server 20.0.2 embedded in Spring Boot application with DB2 using following steps:

1. I have generated the db script and executed it on DB2.
2. I have updated the script manually to make it compatible with DB2 and now all the tables are created in my DB2.

**Problem**:
When I start the embedded Keycloak server, it tries to update the tables again and fail at the queries which I had manually corrected in the script.
***How can I stop embedded Keycloak server from updating the database during startup and use the tables created through script?***

**Note**: I have refered [this](https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app) link to embed Keycloak server in Spring Boot application.